# Flipview mouse scroll preventing webview mouse scroll in Windows 8.1

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml, windows-8.1

I have a FlipView control with a webview as the Item template. I want to enable horizontal scrolling of the WebView on mouse scroll if the content loaded into the webview is wider than the width. It seems that the FlipView mouse scroll swallows any horizontal scrolling inside a FlipView child. Any help?

FlipView XAML

```
<FlipView
        x:Name="flipView"
        AutomationProperties.AutomationId="ItemsFlipView"
        AutomationProperties.Name="Item Details"
        TabIndex="1"
        ItemTemplate="{StaticResource FlipViewTemplate}"
        ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource itemsViewSource}}"
            Grid.RowSpan="2" Padding="120,10,40,10">
        <FlipView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="FlipViewItem">
                <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,0,0,0"/>
            </Style>
        </FlipView.ItemContainerStyle>
    </FlipView>
```

FlipView DataTemplate

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="FlipViewTemplate">
            <WebView common:WebViewExtensions.HTML="{Binding Converter={StaticResource ArticleConverter}}" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"/>
        </DataTemplate>
```

Comment: Would a solution that disables the FlipView behavior be okay?

Comment: Ok, share it and we see